# Write a function to generate all strings between two given strings

Tags: c#, algorithm

Write a function to generate all strings between two given strings, for example if first string is “ABC01” and second is “ADE05” following list should be the result of the code. Incrementing the integers and alphabets in chronological order.

Assuming Alphabet or integer in second string is always greater than first string. If there is an integer at 4th and 5th index in first string then in second string 4th and 5th index is an integer. "BBBBB" and "BBB05" is invalid

Input: "ABC01" "ADE05"

Output sequence:

ABC01,ABC02,ABC03,ABC04,ABC05,
ABD01,ABD02,ABD03,ABD04,ABD05,
ABE01,ABE02,ABE03,ABE04,ABE05,
ACC01,ACC02,ACC03,ACC04,ACC05,
ACD01,ACD02,ACD03,ACD04,ACD05,
ACE01,ACE02,ACE03,ACE04,ACE05,
ADC01,ADC02,ADC03,ADC04,ADC05,
ADD01,ADD02,ADD03,ADD04,ADD05,
ADE01,ADE02,ADE03,ADE04,ADE05

I have tried following but it only update last digit. Can anyone suggest implementation for generating this sequence in any language. Thanks in advance

```
public class PrintStringSequence
{
    static void PrintSequence(String string1, String string2)
    {
        if (string1.Length != string2.Length)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String length should be equal");
            return;
        }

        char[] start = string1.ToCharArray();
        char[] end = string2.ToCharArray();
        String res = "";
        
            for (char letter0 = start[0]; letter0 <= end[0]; letter0++)
            {
                for (char letter1 = start[1]; letter1 <= end[1]; letter1++)
                {
                    for (char letter2 = start[2]; letter2 <= end[2]; letter2++)
                    {
                         for (char letter3 = start[3]; letter3 <= end[3]; letter3++)
                         {   
                             for (char letter4 = start[4]; letter4 <= end[4]; letter4++)
                             {
                                 res = string1.Remove(4).Insert(4, letter4.ToString());
                                 Console.WriteLine(res);
                             }
                             res = string1.Remove(3).Insert(3, letter3.ToString());
                         }
                         res = string1.Remove(2).Insert(2, letter2.ToString());
                    }
                    res = string1.Remove(1).Insert(1, letter1.ToString());
                }
                res = string1.Remove(0).Insert(0, letter0.ToString());
            }     
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        PrintSequence("ABC01", "ADE05");
    }
}
```

I am getting
[image]

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* - This is not a useful problem description. What follows is basically "give me teh codez". What inputs did you provide? What output did you get? What did you expect? What did you observe when you stepped through the code? You did step through the code, right?

Comment: I don't think I follow the requirements.  One of your examples in the output is `ADD05` but the `D` only appears in the third position of the second input, how is it possible for one of the outputs to have it twice in different positions?  Does that mean that `BBBBB` is also a valid output?

Comment: it only updates 5th index number and does not update any other index. Help bro

Comment: Is `BBBBB` a valid expected output for your example inputs? if not why is `ADD05` valid?  What _exactly_ does _"all strings between two given strings"_ mean?

Comment: You are throwing away the outer changes when reentering the inner for loops. You always go from string1. `Remove` and `Insert` **create new strings**. They do not mutate string1.

Comment: Alphabet or integer in second string is always greater than first string.

Comment: @AceGambit Assuming if there is an integer at index 4 and 5 in first string then in second string 4th and 5th index is an integer

Comment: Initialize `res` with `string1` and use `res` where you have `string1` in the loops. You need to reassign the changes to itself.

Comment: And then find an algorithm that doesn't produce tons of strings in the process. :D

Comment: @Fildor I assigned the res to string1 but still it does update sequence. Help bro

Comment: Don't tag spam unless you're looking to draw negative attention.

Comment: I have compiled an answer that should explain and fix your problem. I just wouldn't recommend _actually_ doing it that way. So look at it more as an explanation than a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate from right to left.

E.g. For `1` to `5`, you create 5 arrays `{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}`.

For each of those 5 arrays, you prepend the next element, `0`. It is the same, so you would have no nested loops. You now have `{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}`.

Then `C` to `E`, this has a nested loop. `{C, 0, 1}`, `{D, 0, 1}, {E, 0, 1}, {C, 0, 2}`, and so on. Should end up with 15 elements.

... Repeat until you reach index zero in both strings. Then convert those arrays into strings, and print. If order matters, then sort the strings afterwards rather than during this process.

Ideally, you check that your input strings have the same length before starting this process, as well as validate each index are both digits or letters, as you mention.

Comment: bro can you suggest function implementation in any language. Thanks for your help

Comment: This algorithm can be accomplished in any language. I was pointing out that you probably don't need 5 nested loops. You generate one array-of-arrays at a time and keep two indicies for the original strings. And you shouldn't print the content immediately from modifying the same string

Answer (score 1):

your approach for nested for loops, one for each letter, may end up being potentially technically correct; however, it is extremely inflexible and not really in DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) best practices.  I would advise iterating over each index of the first string and adding to it until you get to the next string.  Break the problem into pieces.  First figure out how to find all the characters between two characters, and then use that to find all the strings between two strings by applying that function to each character.

Something like

```
public char[] FindAllCharactersBetween(char start, char end)
{
  var result = new List<char>();
  var iter = start + 1;
  while(iter < end) 
  {
    result.Add(iter);
    iter++;
  }
  return result.ToArray();
}
```

Use something like that to iterate over each index of start and substitute the results of that function in for each character.

Answer (score 1):

Increment the rightmost character, starting from the first value, until the second one (e.g. from 1 to 5). Then reset to the first and carry to the next character to the left. Note that in the case of the 0, the carry immediately causes an overflow of the value, causing a reset and a carry to the next (C). The enumeration stops on a carry out of the leftmost character.

ABC01 > ABC02 > ABC03 > ABC04 > ABC05 > ABC0**6**=ABC**1**1=ABD01 > ABD02 > ABD03 > ABD04 > ABD05 > ABD0**6**0=ABD**1**1=ABE01 > ABE02 > ABE03 > ABE04 > ABE05 > ABE0**6**=ABE**1**1=AB**F**11=ACC01 ...

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. bro can you suggest function implementation in any language. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @desimizaj: I explained it in natural language.

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
var start = "the cat";
for (int i =0; i<5; i++)
{
    var loop = start.Remove(0);
    Console.WriteLine(loop);
}
```

you will get 5 times `"he cat"`. `Remove` does not mutate the original string. Neither does `Insert`.

If you need to keep changes, you need to reassign the var:

```
var start = "the cat";
for (int i =0; i<5; i++)
{
    start = start.Remove(0);
    Console.WriteLine(start);
}
```

Will then go

```
he cat
e cat
 cat
cat
at
```

Note that this only explains why your code does what it does and how you can fix that.

The result would still be highly inefficient and inflexible.

The changes for you would be:

```
String res = string1;
        
for (char letter0 = start[0]; letter0 <= end[0]; letter0++)
{
    for (char letter1 = start[1]; letter1 <= end[1]; letter1++)
    {
        for (char letter2 = start[2]; letter2 <= end[2]; letter2++)
        {
             for (char letter3 = start[3]; letter3 <= end[3]; letter3++)
             {   
                 for (char letter4 = start[4]; letter4 <= end[4]; letter4++)
                 {
                     res = res.Remove(4).Insert(4, letter4.ToString());
                     Console.WriteLine(res);
                 }
                 res = res.Remove(3).Insert(3, letter3.ToString());
             }
             res = res.Remove(2).Insert(2, letter2.ToString());
        }
        res = res.Remove(1).Insert(1, letter1.ToString());
    }
    res = res.Remove(0).Insert(0, letter0.ToString());
}
```

I have not tested it, though.

Also: **Do not use in production code**! Find a better solution. This is for educational purposes at best.

Comment: I have tested this change but it doesn't update rest of the indexes. i think i need to update the algo according to answers

Comment: The main purpose of the answer was to show why your code is behaving as it does. So yes, absolutely. Do not actually use this code.